# Фокус в listView

Tags: android-sdk, android, java, activity

Есть listView и item.xml.
В item.xml есть textView и LinearLayout, в LinearLayout background синего цвета.  
В listView указан параметр, listSelector=#ff0000, то есть красный цвет.

Как сделать, чтобы  при клике на item цвет поменялся из синего в красный с фокусом?

P.S. Если выбрать другой item, то предыдущий item опять будет синим, а выбранный - красным.

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо смотреть в сторону вот этой [статьи](http://tokudu.com/post/50023900640/android-checkable-linear-layout) 
только в соответствующих методах меняйте фон элемента.

и не забыть об этом

```
listVIew.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

Comment: А почему этот код не работает для ListView, я этот selector подключаю в listSelector
http://pastebin.com/A0qpkaV9